# How can I convert string to numpy.array inside a DataFrame column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

My DataFrame db is built from a csv file, using read_csv. Values of column A look like this:

```
[1,2,5,6,48,125]
```

On every row, the "vector" can have a different length. But it is still a string.
I can strip the [ and ] as follows:

```
db["A"] = db["A"].str.rstrip(']').str.lstrip('[')
```

The resulting values, such as `1,2,5,6,48,125`, should be good input for np.fromstring. However, I am not able to apply this function in combination with pandas DataFrame.

When I try:
`db["A"] = np.fromstring(db["A"], sep=',')`, it says:
a bytes-like object is required, not 'Series'.
Using `apply` also does not work. Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2):

One idea is convert values to lists and then to `np.array`:

```
import ast

db["A"] = db["A"].apply(lambda x: np.array(ast.literal_eval(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
for i in range(0, len(db)-1):
  db["A"] = np.array(db.iloc[i]["A"])
  continue
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.fromarray()` is built for this purpose like you(OP) already pointed out. The problem here is that the input isn't being recognized as a string.

However this addresses the problem,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'data': ["[1,2,4]", "[1,2,4,5]","[1,2,4,5,6]"]})
dataframe['data'] = dataframe['data'].apply(lambda x : np.fromstring(str(x).replace('[','').replace(']',''), sep=','))
```

The output will be an 1D- `nparray`

Running `dataframe.head()` gives me this

```
    data
0   [1.0, 2.0, 4.0]
1   [1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0]
2   [1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```